# Storyboard show viewcontrollers in reversed Preview (Xcode 8.3.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode8

**Xcode 8.3.2** shows the viewControllers in a reversed preview like a mirror (screenshot attached). I don't know whether it's an Xcode bug or a hidden feature. I'm facing a problem due to this. Is there any way to recover the viewControllers in the original preview and to resolve this issue?

[image: ViewController in Reversed Preview]

Comment: Funny! Never have seen this.

Comment: yes @YunCHEN but i'm continuously facing this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard lagging due to many viewControllers and continuously changing the viewcontrollers causes this problem to occur in Xcode 8.3.2. So everytime I needed to quit and reopen the storyboard resolve this issue.

Now, I have updated Xcode to version **Xcode 9.2** and issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Just close the Xcode project completely and then reopen it. It worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the Xcode.Because the same problem was faced by me.
I think it happens when me having many viewController in storyBoard and we keep changing the file at that time this occur.